# How to combine more plots in single image inside a loop

Tags: plotting

I was reading basic help here
[How to | Combine Two or More Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CombineTwoOrMoreGraphics.html)
, but I did not get it.

I have simple differential equation and want to change a constant "b" (in this case "damping") and plot all graphs in a single image.
Here is the code:

```
(*Single mass damper system of a rail car *)
(*with 10 mm starting deflection *)
m = 40000;     (* [kg]    *)
k = 1600000; (* [N/m]   *)

for[b=0, b<=160000, b=b+20000,

sol = NDSolve[{
m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t]== 0,
x'[0] == 0,x[0] == 0.01},
x[t], {t, 0, 10}];

Print[Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 3}, 
PlotRange -> Full ,
PlotTheme -> {"Grid"},
AxesLabel->{"Time [s]", "Vertical suspension deflection [m]"}, 
PlotLabel->Style["Single mass damper system of a rail car", 12, Bold]]] 
]
```

Can anyone please help?
I'm just missing "hold on" from Matlab here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to use the procedural programming you are used from Matlab usually wont give you a nice solution in mathematica. The more idiomatic Mathematica way is usually shorter and easier. Your problem gets very easy like that: `sols=Table[x[t]/.NDSolve[{m*x''[t]+b*x'[t]+k*x[t]==0,x'[0]==0,x[0]==0.01},x[t],{t,0,10}],{b,0,160000,20000}];
Plot[sols,{t,0,3}]`

Comment: You should also be aware that `for` is not the same as `For`.

Comment: I also recommend looking up `ParametricNDSolveValue`, which makes is much easier to solve DEs for different parameter values.

Comment: Thank you all for the hints! I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

m = 40000;
k = 1600000;
```

Your equation can be solved exactly with [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol = DSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t] == 0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 1/100}, 
    x[t], t][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
sol2 = sol // ExpToTrig // Simplify
```

[image]

Plotting,

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[x[t] /. sol,
   {b, 0, 160000, 20000}], {t, 0, 3},
 PlotTheme -> "Grid",
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
    {"Time [s]", 
     "Vertical suspension deflection [m]"}),
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Single mass damper system of a rail car", 12, Bold],
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[Range[0, 160000, 20000],
   LegendLabel -> Style["b =", 12, Bold]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfect! I appreciate your help.